# Carry on bag with wheels that I can attach to my waist?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

What is a waist strap to put a carry on bag?                                           I have crushed bones.

Comment: I did not think the question unclear, even though it could do with some edits. I also think there might be an other question with useful information, but I can not find it. (One answer was about a two wheeled luggage cart that is connected at the waist, either here or in GTO).

Comment: Jason, can you  explain why you can't pull a roll-a-board or other wheeled "hand luggage" by holding the handle? And why you can't request a wheelchair at the airport so that someone else will take care of your hand luggage? That will give people the details they need to suggest particular luggage options.

Comment: @Willeke are you recollecting [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37205)?

Comment: @Giorgio, no, that one is either dragged or has a waist strap, the one I remember has two wheels on the ground and a waist strap to pull it along.

Answer (score 2):

There are luggage carts which run on two wheels and have a waist strap.
It is hard to find them online, only [one for sale](https://hipstar.net/) (as far as I found them) and that one is not for sale yet.

But I have seen earlier versions in the past, so long ago that google can not find the photos from the few details I remember.

You can also buy a [shopping trolley](https://www.google.nl/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fs3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com%2F10toptest-nl-media%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F02%2F26073142%2F1.-Secc-by-Davidts-Stockolm-Boodschappentrolley.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2F10toptest.nl%2Fgoedkope-aanbieding%2Fbeste-boodschappenwagen%2F&docid=LgErAn9RLtpViM&tbnid=zpQmrZ44tDTDNM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwi5lMLnrvHjAhXJyaQKHSBoAtsQMwjyASgBMAE..i&w=300&h=300&hl=nl&bih=774&biw=1443&q=boodschappenkarretje%20test&ved=0ahUKEwi5lMLnrvHjAhXJyaQKHSBoAtsQMwjyASgBMAE&iact=mrc&uact=8) or the right kind of bike luggage car (which looks like such a shopping trolley) and adjust them. Add a connection to your waist, remembering that is has to be easy to remove it.

Or, you can ask for assistance at the airport, as they will help you with your 'more standard' luggage.